# Instagram iOS Webview doesn't remove %20 in sms link

Tags: html, ios, webview, instagram

I'm trying to invoke the following url in Instagram on iOS 10.3.1:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <a href="sms:+1234;body=This%20is%20the%20body">Click Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening this code in Safari, Chrome, and even other webviews correctly replaces the %20 encoding with a space character. However, opening it in an Instagram webview does not. The messages app opens and directs to the correct number, but the body is prepopulated as "This%20is%20the%20body" instead of the expected "This is the body".

I suspect that Instagram is doing some extra handling of links that does not play well with sms links. Has anyone successfully pre-populated the sms body in Instagram?

Note that Instagram on Android works correctly - this only affects iOS.

Comment: IMHO, it looks like someone at Instagram forgot to decode things properly... Not sure if there's a way to report a bug.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, did you find a solution by any chance?